# Wick contraction with color

Tags: color

I am trying to Wick contract the expression below.
[image]

Provided that the fields for a given contraction have the same color. A generic piece of code is given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}    
\begin{document}
\wick{\c3{E}\c1{A}\c2{B}\c1{C}\c2{D}\c3{F}}
\end{document}
```

I need to put colors for three different contractions: `AC`, `BD`, and `EF`. One way of doing this is to place the arguments for a given contraction next to one another and place them inside `\textcolor{}{}`.

```
\wick{\textcolor{red}{\c1{A}\c1{C}}\textcolor{blue}{\c2{B}\c2{D}}\textcolor{green}{\c3{E}\c2{F}}}
```

But I don't want to do that. What I am trying to achieve is to do contraction, without changing the positions of the arguments. Can anyone please help with this problem?

Comment: Could you please add a sketch of the expected output?

Comment: Sorry, but the edit is not sufficient: where would you apply colors?